Error 21920418 / Regulatory document ID(s) **** not found. Please use valid ID(s)
For the new eBay GPSR rule, I have successfully used the Meta API to create and upload the required document. The document was approved, and I verified it using this URL: https://docs.ebay.com/document/****.
However, when I try to add the document to my listing using the Trading API (AddItem or ReviseItem), I keep getting the following error:

"Regulatory document ID(s) **** not found. Please use valid ID(s)."

The document ID is valid, as it works when I check it through the URL mentioned above.
Has anyone else faced this issue? Any guidance on resolving it would be appreciated.
Trading API request (Additem):

addItem["Item"]["Regulatory"]["Documents"] = StructNew();
addItem["Item"]["Regulatory"]["Documents"]["Document"] = ArrayNew(1);
addItem["Item"]["Regulatory"]["Documents"]["Document"][1]["DocumentID"] = "*****************";


Response:
Regulatory document ID(s) **** not found. Please use valid ID(s).
